# SPARQL CONSTRUCT expressivity

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

Are there any metrics or analysis on how expressive SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries are? Are there graphs or transformations that can't be expressed via CONSTRUCT? What are the limitations?

Comment: I think as phrase, this is probably too broad.  Any graph can be built using a construct query.  It would just look like `construct { triple1 . triple2 . ... }`.  Is there a specific transformation you're wondering whether is possible?

Comment: The question was deliberately broad. Obviously any graph, not quads as pointed out by Michael, can be built in the construct portion but it's not as obvious that any graph transformation can be expressed such as arbitrary variable length lists as pointed out by AndyS.

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL is pspace-complete, like SQL.  It doesn't matter which form you're using.

I'd say the primary limitation of construct queries is that they cannot construct quads.

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary variable length list is not possible in a single CONSTRUCT.  The template can't be written because the CONSTRUCT template is a fixed pattern.

Comment: In researching an answer to this I came across this interesting post [Sparql Abuse](http://brunni.de/sparql_abuse.html)

Comment: Any suggestions or links to ways to work around this limitation?